# How the FileWriter.append works internally

Tags: java, filewriter

I have a situation , I created a file  , created FW object. Then I use writer.append .

**So first I append , header column.**

Then I loop through all the  remaining data and append it.

Then After competion of loop , I do flush() and close().

But I manually throws an exception inside the loop.

So In ideal situation :  there should not be any content in the file.

But I see , the header row , presents in the file.

So is there any way to sort this out.

Here Is code  snippet , not full bcoz it's contains more lines.

```
try {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(targetFile);         
     //  Write Header.
    writer.append(ReportUtil.createString(getHeader(), delimiter));
    writer.append("\r\n");

    for (Object data : (List<Object>) results) {

             // Throws An Error

    }
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    logger.info("End Successfully :: Reports Generation ");
catch (Exception e) {           
    logger.error("Error in  Reports Generation . Please Rerun This Report ::: " + s);
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you post the code you have that's causing the problems?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code, don't try to post it as a comment. They're really not designed for formatting multi-line code blocks, and they don't have the length for more than short/trivial sections of code.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply first prepare your String/bytes/whatever you want to write and only if there is no exception while doing this, write the whole thing in one go?

Comment: I can do that , but the data which I am writing is dynamic and on daily basis. Though I have the Exception Checks , but still I cann't be sure .

Comment: I think there is a slight misunderstanding, since I do not see why that would prevent the use of an internal buffer before writing the actual data...?